# Tkinter treeview not being placed at the right coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I have placed a treeview widget in my tk window with .place() but it is being placed in the wrong coordinates, around 100 pixels off in both x and y, verging closer to 0. The size of the treeview is also affected, making it smaller than it should be. None of my other widgets have this problem.

This only happens on my laptop and not on any other computers. My laptop display is 1920x1080.

Are there any settings that would fix this?

Here is an example. The buttons are placed at the same coordinates as the treeview, but for me, the buttons appear at the right coordinates but the treeviews don't.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import customtkinter as ctk

class Example(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('720x800')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        container = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames={}

        for F in (A, B):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= 'nsew')
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
             

        self.show_frame(A) 

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont] 
        frame.tkraise()

class A(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self,parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='grey') 

        columns = ('ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=columns, show='headings', height=10, selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.place(x=100, y=400)

        #Add Headings 
        for i in range(len(columns)): 
                self.tree.heading(columns[i], text=columns[i])

        #Configure column sizes 
        for i in range (len(columns)): 
                self.tree.column(columns[i], width=141)

        recs = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
        for row in recs:
            self.tree.insert('', tk.END, values=row)

        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self, 
                                    text='Next page', 
                                    command=lambda:controller.show_frame(B))
        self.button.place(x=100, y=400)

class B(tk.Frame): 
     def __init__(self,parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='grey')

        columns = ('ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=columns, show='headings', height=10, selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.place(x=100, y=400)

        #Add Headings 
        for i in range(len(columns)): 
                self.tree.heading(columns[i], text=columns[i])

        #Configure column sizes 
        for i in range (len(columns)): 
                self.tree.column(columns[i], width=141)

        recs = [[6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4]]
        for row in recs:
            self.tree.insert('', tk.END, values=row)

        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self, 
                                    text='Prev page', 
                                    command=lambda:controller.show_frame(A))
        self.button.place(x=100,y=400)
        

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    testWindow= Example() 
    testWindow.mainloop()
```

On my laptop:
[image]

What it's supposed to look like:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve]. "wrong coordinates" is a useless description. Is it off by 1 pixel? 10? 100? 1000? some random amount?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, my mistake. I've now included more details as well as a reproducible example.

Comment: What does "the buttons appear at the right coordinates but the treeviews don't." mean? Where are you expecting the treeview to be? You're putting the button and the treeview at the same coordinates so it's not clear why you think they should be in different places.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have added pictures so that it is more clear. I have ran the same program on two different machines, one is my laptop (first picture, placing the treeview at the wrong coordinates) and the other is another computer showing what it should look like.

Comment: So you are intentionally covering your `ID` column with your button?  Setting that aside have you looked at scaling settings on your computers? Regardless of what the display resolution is many computers have a scale setting that isn't set at 100% for default.

Comment: @Rory Yeah, at the time i thought it would be easier for people to see how much the treeview has displaced if i put like a marker at its original place. But yes, the scaling seemed to be the issue. Mine was set to 150%. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Make sure that your scaling (System>Display>Scale) is set at 100%.